# laravel 5.5.44 post router throws 302 Found Error

Tags: post, laravel-5, routes, http-status-code-302

Facing 302 Found error when trying to update using a `post` method in a route.

**Route**

```
Route::post('update_article/{id}', 'ArticleController@update_article')->name('articles.update');
```

**Edit Form Blade**

```
{!! Form::model($article, ['route'=>['articles.update', $article->id], 'method' => 'post', 'class' => 'form-horizontal form-stripe']) !!}
```

**Controller**

```
public function update_article(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $data = Article::find($id);
        $url = $this->url->to('/');       
        $data->image = $request->input('image');
        $data->title = $request->input('title');
        $data->description = $request->input('description');
        $data->user_id = Auth::id();
        $data->status = $request->input('status');


       if ($request->hasFile('image')) 
       {
        $f_imageName = time().'.'.request()->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        request()->image->move(public_path('uploads/articles'), $f_imageName);
        $data->image =$url.'/public/uploads/articles/'.$f_imageName; 
       }
       else
       {
        $data->image = $request->input('image_hidden');    
       }

    $data->save();   
    Session::flash('success', 'articles has been updated');
    return redirect()->route('articles.index');
    }
```

Using `POST` for updating instead of `PUT` as i am using summernote. When i use `PUT`, large `description` gets truncated. In summernote it states that it may happen if i do not use `POST` method.

And there is also a default route just before the `update_article` route for articles resources as:

```
Route::resource('articles', 'ArticleController');
```

Note: `csrf token` is sent as `_token` params in the post operation. Cannot find any solution yet. Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I changed the DB structure to type `text` from `varchar` and long description is not being truncated using `PUT` method instead of `POST` in the update operation. So, gone back to default routing using method `PUT` in form submit-

**Route:**

```
Route::resource('articles', 'ArticleController');
```

Everything works now as expected.

Answer (score 1):

If you have created the resource as you mentioned.

```
Route::resource('articles', 'ArticleController');
```

then remove the following code from your route `web.php` and run the code.

```
Route::post('update_article/{id}', 'ArticleController@update_article')->name('articles.update');
```

Comment: in that case, update operation does not allow `post` method, it says `HttpMethodException`, only put or patch is allowed in that case. As i have mentioned, i cannot use `PUT` as it truncated the description field of summernote, i need to use `POST`. The default resource route requires the method to be `put` here.

Comment: any suggestion ?

Comment: are u submitting the form with ajax? if yes please check form data in the console. i think description field is empty. laravel is not truncating.

Comment: no, i am using normal form submit, and the description field is not empty, it has text value.

Comment: solved it by changing the db structure and followed your suggestion, thanks

Comment: that's perfect :)